# Add Property to Properties Window

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I have built a UserControl class and am exposing certain properties to the parent object.

When i drag and drop the component to the parent objects designer surface, i get the effect i need (per say).  What i want to further develop is the ability to pre-fill the property value (in properties window) as a default but it isnt auto-populating as i would have expected.

Here is what i have so far:

```
<Browsable(True), Category("Data"),
DefaultValue("01/01/1990")>
Public Property [Date] As String
    Get
        Return Me._dt
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me._dt = value
        dtValue.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I understand that `DefaultValueAttribute` assigns the value if no other assignments are made, but thought it would also place that value in the field in the Properties Window.

As well, this ultimate assignment will go up one more level as a collection, so any advise or URL's for how to make a Collection of Components available via Properties Window?

Comment: Before anyone says anything, I mean to use `[Date]`.  It is pertinent to the value assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that DefaultValueAttribute assigns the value if no other assignments are made

That is incorrect.

The `DefaultValueAttribute` is just metadata that tells the designer what the default is.

It is still up to your code to ensure that the property actually gets that value.

Comment: and yet the designer isnt making the value add.

Comment: @GoldBishop: The designer is not supposed to.  `DefaultValue` tells the designer what to _expect_ (what to show as non-bold, and what not to serialize); it doesn't ever set a value.

Comment: but shouldn't it auto-fill the `DefaultValue` into the Designer?

Comment: @GoldBishop: No.  The designer will create an actual instance of your class, and will read the property's actual value.

Comment: So if i want a default value i should load that value into the `New` method?  Just trying to get a greater understanding of some of these attributes.  Trying to not be one of those devs that uses it just cause its convenient.

Comment: @GoldBishop: Correct.  `DefaultValue` only affects how the designer behaves.

Comment: Is there a way of making it so that the property in the Designer is preloaded with value(s)?  That is my ultimate goal, is have default designer behavior/value, in case the user of the control does not edit it and i can trap for that default value.

Comment: @GoldBishop: No.  The designer creates an actual instance of your class; you can make that instance do whatever you want it to.  You can also abuse `ShouldSerialize*()` and `Reset*()`.

Comment: I prefer not abusing anything right now as im sorta new to VS component development.  Want to learn how to walk before i run a TriAthelon.